# Extracting KIA care update firmware

Tags: firmware-analysis, binwalk

I have a new KIA sportage NQ5 car. Now I want to enable wifi and turn on ADB so I can install custom app and use AA Wireless or Carplay wireless. Sadly, the old trick to access android setting app does not work any more on the latest Vietnam region firmware.

I downloaded the firmware and there is a file called usb_upgrade.bin which I believe that it is used to update the firmware and lock the old trick access. Tried using binwalk with command
`binwalk -Mre usb_update.bin --run-as=root` and it did some job. I even found many apk files (incompleted, no extension, open with 7zip and there are contents of an APK), an android file system update tree(extractable, incomplete, missing symbol links), an Uboot image which I can't extract and many other files.

The problem is those files that I tried to open is incompleted or encrypted somehow. The contents inside almost unreadable, even when they are xml file.

Can any one have a look at this file and give me some advices?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LXOlowXuT2sjnt7AJqiewruJ6Ny2n63b/view?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most XML files used in Android use a binary XML format, most likely this is why you think they are "encrypted".  There are various ways/tools to decode such files to plain text XML. See e.g. https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/axml.html

Comment: @Robert I managed to decrypt those XML files :D just the APK is actually not recognizable by the androguard somehow. The binwalk can't extract that bin file completely so there are missing symbol links and things after finished.